# Writing char pointer as struct member to file issue

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char, fwrite

I have a struct member as a char * and assign it to a string literal "John" on the struct initialisation as shown below. The string prints fine with printf.

However, if I write this string to a file using fwrite, in the file I read back garbage.

If I use a char array instead of a char * (commented out in the struct as shown), and write it to the file, I can read back the string in the file as expected. I can't understand this. Shouldn't fwrite in both cases take the pointer and write the correct string to the file?

Furthermore , if I declare a separate char * and point it to a string literal and write it to the file, I can read it back as expected. Many thanks in advance for any help with explanation. (I am using codeblocks IDE with Mingw compiler on Windows).

UPDATED : To include actual code used

```
int main()
{
    struct person
    {
        //char name[20];
        char* name;
        int age;
    };

    struct person p1 = {"John", 25};

    printf("%s\n", p1.name);
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fwrite(&p1, 1, 10, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How* do you write and read the string to get "garbage"? Do you write the whole structure in a single `fwrite` call? Please try o create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the *failing* program and show us.

Comment: While you do that, you should learn that pointers are specific to a single process, and if you write the full structure in a single call to `fwrite` you write the *pointer* and not what it points to. The `fwrite` function doesn't know anything about the data it writes, all it has is a series of anonymous bytes.

Comment: I'd appreciate a more classy reply. This is a place for learning and helping others, not to show arrogance.

Comment: **You** are showing arrogance. The comment asking for a [mcve] is just an application of SO rules. Give one and you will get answers explaining what is wrong and how to fix it. But without it, we can only try to guess and currently I cannot know where your problem can be.

Comment: I ask a question - get into an argument straight away. This is what happens here mostly. I don't see any issue with my question. Anyone decent who can reply in a good manner? Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, it will work with pointer or char array. Could you give us your whole test code ? I.e. how did you check that it did not work, where is your main function, etc.

Comment: @Engineer999 the code you show should write "john" + some garbage bytes to test.txt. Why garbage bytes ? Because you the length of the string "John" is 4, but you write 10 bytes. Besides that you should show a [mcve], because we don't know how you read the file. The more information you show in your questio, the better will be the answers.

Comment: @Michael Walz and @ staringlizard . No, when using a char pointer, it prints only garbage to the file, When I use a char array , it prints the expected string.

Comment: @Engineer999 about every comment and even the only answer is asking for a [mcve]. So why don't you provide one ?

Comment: @Engineer999 what you write would apply if your writing code was this: `fwrite(&p1, 1, 10, fp);` instead of `fwrite(p1.name, 1, 10, fp);`.

Comment: @Michael Walz. I've included the actual test code. Yes, sorry, it is only when I do fwrite(&p1,1,10,fp). Why is this the case?

Comment: @Engineer999 well I hope now you understand why it is important to provide __all__ information people are asking for. Writing the answer right now...

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete. You are missing *at least* the required `#include <stdio.h>`. You also aren't showing how you read the file. Do you read the file from a C program (if so, the same program or a different one)? Or are you just examining the file? We can't guess what else you may have left out.

Since you don't know what the problem is, you almost by definition do not know what information you can safely omit. That's why everyone is asking you for a [mcve] -- **because we can't help you without it**.

Comment: I can tell you that writing 10 bytes of `p1` doesn't make sense; the structure is likely to be bigger than 10 bytes. How did you decide that 10 is the correct number of bytes to write?

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Yes I am just examining the file. I normally don't like to include complete code as someone told me before when I done that, that this is not a debugging forum , which I understand. Thanks, I see the problem now

Comment: @Engineer999: That's that the "Minimal" in [mcve] is about. Please read that link. You shouldn't post an entire large program that's not entirely relevant to your problem. You should narrow down your program to something smaller that still clearly demonstrates your problem. And if you're just examining the file, not reading  it in a C program, please say so *in the question*.

Answer (score 3):

The commenters are saying that the code you provided does not give enough information to solve your problem. It looks like the error lies elsewhere in your code. I can convert your code to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person
{
    //char name[20];
    char* name;
    int age;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct person p1 = {"John", 25};

    printf("%s\n", p1.name);

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fwrite(p1.name, 1, 10, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    char buffer[20];
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fread(buffer, 1, 10, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("The stored name is: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

But I am sure that what you have differs, because this code works:

```
John
The stored name is: John
```

### Update

From the new code that you provided, I can see that your problem is that you are writing the contents of a `struct` to a file instead of writing a string to a file, as in your original code example.

The original code used:

```
fwrite(p1.name, 1, 10, fp);
```

and wrote 10 bytes of the string `p1.name` to the file `"test.txt"` (blowing right past the `NUL` terminator of the string `"John"` and saving garbage values that would not be seen on printing the string).

The new code uses:

```
fwrite(&p1, 1, 10, fp);
```

saving the first 10 bytes of the `struct` `p1` to the file `"test.txt"`.

When the `struct` contains `char name[20];`, the first 10 bytes are `char`s stored in the character array `name`, and this is why your code appeared to work in this case.

When the `struct` instead contains `char *name;`, the first few bytes saved belong to the pointer `name`(8 bytes on my system), not to the string literal `"John"`. The next few bytes belong to the `int` `age`(4 bytes on my system). It is these values and not the `char`s of the string literal `"John"` that are being saved in this case.

Note that the sizes of pointers and `int`s may be different on different systems, and it is entirely possible to have 4 bytes for the pointer and 4 bytes for the `int`, leaving 2 bytes which are saved that are not part of the `struct`. Also, though this does not affect you here, there may be padding after the first member of the `struct`.

Comment: I'm sure your code is quite different from the OP's. I don't understand why he won't post an MCVE.

Answer (score 3):

With this structure definition:

```
struct person
{
    char* name;
    int age;
};
```

following code won't do what you expect:

```
struct person p1 = {"John", 25};

printf("%s\n", p1.name);
FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fwrite(&p1, 1, 10, fp);
```

The reason is that bytes of the variable `p1`: doesn't actually contain the string "John", but it contains a **pointer** to the string "John", that is a the memory address of the string "John". Now `fwrite(&p1, 1, 10, fp);` will write 10 bytes starting from the memory address of `p1`, that is (assuming a 32 bit system): 4 bytes representing the pointer which is just some memory address, 4 bytes representing `1` (age) and 2 bytes that follow in memory that don't belong to the `p1`variable.

Now if the structure is define like this:

```
struct person
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
};
```

The situation is entirely different. This time the variable `p1` actually does contain the string "John". the first 4 bytes contain the characters `J`, `o`, `h`,  `n` then follows a NUL character which is the string terminator and then follow 15 bytes of undetermined value. Then follow 4 bytes representing `age`.

In that case the `fwrite(&p1, 1, 10, fp);` will again write 10 bytes starting from the memory address of `p1`, but as explained in the paragraph above, the first 4 bytes contain "John", the 5th byte contains the NUL terminator and the 5 remaining bytes are of indeterminate value.

Comment: You get my vote for sticking with this and providing the correct answer when we finally got to see the code!

Comment: Thanks for that. My confusion is/ was that arrays always get treated the same as pointers . When we pass an array to a function , it is the pointer that gets passed. I was thinking in this case here that fwrite would see what char* name was pointing to and write it.

Comment: @Engineer999 the only thing that `fwrite` "sees" is a pointer to a bunch of bytes and a length. `fwrite` doesn't know anything about what it is writing.